# Sphinx search debugging

Tags: sphinx

We use [Sphinx Search](http://sphinxsearch.com/) at work but and I am having an issue with a new index I'm setting up. Does anyone know of a tool or technique that so I can look at the data stored in Sphinx?

Basically I want to do something like - "show me the first 5 records in index 'X'", just to be sure that it is actually storing data. At the moment I'm about 90% sure that my query code is correct but have no way of knowing that my index is correct.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***SELECT * FROM index_name*** on Sphinx side should give you a list of IDs. This required MySQL protocol support to be enabled in Sphinx conf file:

```
listen = 9306:mysql41
```

Answer (score 0):

To Find Ids in index, you can do this:

/usr/local/sphinx/bin/indextool -c /usr/local/sphinx/etc/sphinx.conf --dumpdocids indexname